# problem making a online site with wampserver

Tags: web, localhost, wamp, wampserver

at first I apologize for my bad english.
I have made a website with a sitebuilder like opencart on wampserver but I have problem to make it online.
I have forwarded port on router settings:

[as you can see i have put 80 port and 443 and also i have tried to put my internet public ip as source ip but no change in results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj5hY.png)
and created inbound and outbounds rules for these ports in firewall

and also changed the config of wampserver from private to online:
[httpd.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHC0w.png)

[phpmyadmin.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/369Mv.png)

but still i cant reach my website by typing my ip in browser.

is there anything else i should do for that ?

Comment: *"I have problem to make it online"* - online as in accessible by everyone on the internet or just in the local network? also, do check if your firewall explicitly allows remote access for those two ports.

Comment: i want it to be accessible by everyone on the internet. about firewall, in additon of adding inbound rules for these ports, also turned it off for no firewall problems.

Comment: uhh, if you want you site to be accessible from the internet, you will need publicly accessible ip address. your `192.168.1.104` is a local one, so does your router's - it usually sits behind your ISP NAT. consumer-grade ISP wont just allow anyone to publish website (or any services, really) this way because reasons, see [this discussion](https://superuser.com/a/1688696). you could use ([free shared](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/20838/73992)) servers out there to host your site.

Comment: How old is your WAMPServer, that code is way way old. That should not stop things working but does mean you have a Apache/PHP/MySQL that is old and has known vulnarabilities. I would not suggest using a WAMPServer on a windows PC as a live site anyway, but this is just down right dangerous!